# Newton's method in higher dimensions explained

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

I'm studying about Newton's method and I get the single dimension case perfectly, but the multidimensional version makes me ask question...

In Wikipedia Newton's method in higher dimensions is defined as:

$$\textbf{x}_{n+1} = \textbf{x}_n - [Hf(\textbf{x}_n)]^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf{x}_n), \;\;\; n \geq 0.$$

Where $\textbf{x}_n$ is the $p$-dimensional vector at $n$th iteration, $[Hf(\textbf{x}_n)]^{-1}$ is the inverse of the Hessian matrix of the function $f(\textbf{x})$ at $\textbf{x}_n$ and $\nabla f(\textbf{x}_n)$ is the gradient of the function $f(\textbf{x})$ at $\textbf{x}_n$. That is:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
x_1^{(n+1)}  \\
x_2^{(n+1)}  \\
\vdots \\
x_p^{(n+1)}  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
x_1^{(n)}  \\
x_2^{(n)}  \\
\vdots \\
x_p^{(n)}  \end{array} \right) - \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2}(\textbf{x}_n) & \dots & \dots &\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_p\partial x_1}(\textbf{x}_n)\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}(\textbf{x}_n)  & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1\partial x_p}(\textbf{x}_n) & \dots & \dots & \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_p^2}(\textbf{x}_n)  \end{array} \right)^{-1}\left( \begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(\textbf{x}_n)  \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(\textbf{x}_n)   \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}(\textbf{x}_n)   \end{array} \right)$$

Now my question is: "What is the intuition behind this formula?" This resembles somehow the gradient descent algorithm, but the inverse of the Hessian is like it came from the magician's hat :S Can somebody give me a similar kind of proof as is given here on the one-dimensional case:

[Why does Newton's method work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350740/why-does-newtons-method-work)

Why the Hessian? Why its inverse?! :) Intuition of the formula?

Thank you for any help :) P.S. I here is the page I got the formula above:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions

Note also that in my notation the topscript in the $x_i$s doesn't mean exponent, it's just an iteration label...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll assume we're trying to minimize a twice continuously differentiable function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R^p$.

We wish to find $x$ such that $\nabla f(x) = 0$.

Given $x_n$, we would ideally like to find $\Delta x$ such that $\nabla f(x_n + \Delta x) = 0$.  Rather than satisfying this requirement exactly (which would probably be too difficult), we instead use the approximation
\begin{equation*}
\nabla f(x_n + \Delta x) \approx \nabla f(x_n) + Hf(x_n) \Delta x.
\end{equation*}
Setting the right hand side equal to $0$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
\Delta x = -Hf(x_n)^{-1} \nabla f(x_n).
\end{equation*}
We can hope that $x_{n+1} = x_n + \Delta x$ will be an improvement on $x_n$.

Comment: Note that Newton's method in optimization simply solves $\nabla f(x) = 0$, using Newton's method for solving nonlinear equations.

Comment: What if the Hessian isn't invertible, can you use an approximation like SVD?

Comment: "Newton's method in optimization simply solves ∇()=0, using Newton's method for solving nonlinear equations". I completely disagree, as your answer ignores linesearch/trust region globalization mechanism, the desire to make $f$ decrease from one iteration to the next, and the fact that $f$ may be nonconvex.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another interpretation of Newton's method that I rather like.

Newton's method takes the known information of the function at a given point (value, gradient and Hessian), makes a quadratic approximation of that function, and minimizes that approximation.

More specifically, suppose $x_n$ is given, $g = \nabla f(x_n)$, and $H = \nabla^2 f(x_n)$. The quadratic approximation of $f$ at $x_n$ is a quadratic function $h(x)$ such that $h(x_n) = f(x_n)$, $\nabla h(x_n) = g$ and $\nabla^2 h(x_n) = H$. It turns out that
$$
h(x) = \frac 12(x - x_n)^T H (x - x_n) + g^T (x - x_n) + f(x_n).
$$
This function has a unique global minimum if and only if $H$ is positive definite. This is the requirement for Newton's method to work. Assuming $H$ is positive definite, the minimum of $h$ is achieved at $x^*$ such that $\nabla h(x^*) = 0$. Since
$$
\nabla h(x) = H(x - x_n) + g,
$$
we get $x^* = x_n - H^{-1}g$.

Answer (score 2):

The Hessian is simply the higher-dimensional generalization of the second derivative, and multiplying by its inverse is the non-commutative generalization of dividing by $f''$ in the one-dimensional case. I don't know if it's reasonable to try a geometric argument along the line of your link for the double generalization to optimization and to $n$ dimensions: better to just look up an actual proof.

It might be less confusing if you look at the higher-dimensional Newton's method for roots, before that for optimization. That's the "nonlinear systems of equations" section on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Hubbard and Hubbard's book on linear algebra, multivariable calculus, and differential forms has the best treatment of multivariate Newton's method I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can see Newton's method as a descent direction search method (please see detais in [Why is Newton's method faster than gradient descent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013195/why-is-newtons-method-faster-than-gradient-descent/4404742#4404742) that  I answered before).

To see this, you can consider the minimization problem
$$0=g(\textbf{a})=\min_{\textbf{x}\in A}{g(\textbf{x})},\qquad {g(\textbf{x})}=\frac{1}{2}\|{\bf f}({\bf x})\|^2.$$ to some continuously differentiable function $\textbf{f}:A\to \mathbb{R}^p$, where $A$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ containing $\textbf{a}$.

If you have some differentiable curve $\textbf{u}:(a,b)\to A$, you can apply the chain rule to obtain
$$\frac{d\, g({\bf u}(t))}{dt}= \left\langle {\bf u}'(t), \nabla g({\bf u}(t))\right\rangle=\left\langle J{\bf f}({\bf u}(t)){\bf u}'(t),{\bf f}({\bf u}(t))\right\rangle,$$ in which $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product.

If you choose the curve satisfing the initial value problem (IVP) $$\left\{\begin{array}{rrl}J{\bf f}({\bf u}(t)){\bf u}'(t)&=&-\alpha {\bf f}({\bf u}(t))\\ {\bf u}(0)&=&{\bf u}_0\end{array}\right.,$$ to some $\alpha>0$. You find that $$\frac{d\, g({\bf u}(t))}{dt}= -2\alpha g({\bf u}(t))$$ or $$g({\bf u}(t))=g({\bf u}(0))e^{-2\alpha t}.$$

Newton's method is just the Euler method to solve this IVP numerically.

**Remark:** If $f(x)=\nabla h(x)$ you find the expression in your question, as a particular case. You can find more, if you search to "(x_{n+1} = x_n - [Hf(x_n)]^{-1}\nabla f(x_n))" on SearchOnMath.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if part of your confusion comes from the fact that one-dimensional Newton is usually presented as a method for finding the zero of a function $f(x)$, whereas your higher-dimensional formula is about finding the *minimum* of a function $f(x)$. So you first need to observe that your formula is about finding the zero of $\nabla f$.

In other words: you only need a first derivative in both cases, but since you are getting your formula in an optimization context, the function you are finding the zero of is already a derivative, hence the need for a second derivative.