# Is there an 'inner product wrt a matrix' version of gradient descent?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Gradient descent generally starts with a first order Taylor approximation motivation. If we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$, and we start at a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$, then we can look at the first order Taylor approximation
\begin{align}
f(x+\Delta x)\approx f(x)+\langle\nabla f(x),\Delta x \rangle_{l^2}
\end{align}
We want to have the update $\Delta x$ to point in the same direction as $-\nabla f(x)$ in order to minimize $\langle\nabla f(x),\Delta x \rangle_{l^2}$. However could we use a different inner product? For instance let's say we have an SPD matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ and we use the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_A=x^T A y$. Then we could Taylor approximate
\begin{align}
f(x+\Delta x)\approx f(x)+\langle \nabla f(x),\Delta x\rangle_A
\end{align}
We would then have gradient descent updates
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}=x_n-\eta A\nabla f(x)
\end{align}
where $\eta$ is the learning rate. Is this type of gradient descent an actual procedure? If so, what is it called? If not, what is 'wrong' with it? I'm asking this because [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07572) 'seems' to be doing an infinite dimensional/functional version of this procedure.

Comment: If $A$ is SPD you can write it as $A=P^T P$ for some matrix $P$, which is now essentially the same problem within a different coordinate system.

Comment: Please see my answer to this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013195/why-is-newtons-method-faster-than-gradient-descent/4404742#4404742).

Comment: I just quickly looked at the article mentioned, but I think they use some version to the [representer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representer_theorem#:~:text=For%20computer%20science%2C%20in%20statistical%20learning%20theory%2C%20a,of%20several%20related%20results%20stating%20that%20a%20minimizer).

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo I think it doesn't matter since $A=A^T$. obaarey can you elaborate on this? Not super familiar with solving same problem within different coordinate system.

Comment: Someone pointed out that when you let $A$ be the inverse of the Hessian you actually get a special case of Newton's method for finding roots of the gradient, which is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know if this 'matrix gradient descent' actually has a formal name, we can note that it has nice properties in the gradient flow case. Note that if
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}&=-A\nabla f(x(t))
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial t}&=\nabla f(x(t))^T\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}\\
&=-\nabla f(x(t))^T A \nabla f(x(t))
\end{align*}
where the first line applies the chain rule. So if $A$ is SPD then $\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial t}=0$ iff $\nabla f(x(t))=0$ i.e. $x(t)$ is a critical point. Thus 'matrix' gradient flow is guaranteed to converge to a critical point if the matrix is SPD.