# Newton Raphson Method in optimiztion.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I understand that Newton Raphson Method is used to find the zero of a function. However when I'm trying to find the maximum or minimum point, why does diving the derivative by the second derivative iterate closer to the maximum or minimum point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Newton's method work?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350740/why-does-newtons-method-work)

Comment: I think the piece you might be missing is that minimum/maximum points of a smooth function are roots of the first derivative.  So Newton-Raphson applied to first derivatives entails division (or matrix inversion) using the the second derivatives.

Comment: I get why does it work, thank for your inputs!

Comment: @Alizter Not a duplicate. That posts explains why the method works for roots. Here the OP already knows about roots, and asks why it works for max/min.

Answer (score 1):

As hardmath said

> I think the piece you might be missing is that minimum/maximum points of a smooth function are roots of the first derivative. So Newton-Raphson applied to first derivatives entails division (or matrix inversion) using the the second derivatives.